# Ionizing Radiation Mechanism

Tags: radiation, ionization-energy

I am trying to understand the vapor trails created in my DIY cloud chamber (isopropyl alcohol and dry ice). I've gotten as far as believing that I understand that when, say, an electron, ionizes the molecules in the vapor, then since the alcohol molecules are dipolar, they will condense along the electron trail.  But the actual ionization mechanism eludes me.  I keep seeing verbs like "knock" used. Is that a shorthand for the repulsion of the 2 negative electrical charges plus the velocity of the ionizing electron pushing an electron out of its shell? Also, does a single particle account for all or most of the vapor trail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fancier word for "knock" is [electron impact ionization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_ionization).

Yes, the whole trace is due to the same particle. Typically it will start out with on the order of 1 MeV of kinetic energy.